# couldnt understand the use of this #define

Tags: c++, oracle10g, storage

I am new to one project, where we are using `Oracle 10g` and `C++`. For connectivity to `DB` we are using `Pro*c`. When I was checking that code, I catch one line which is not at all related to `C++`.

```
#define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS extern
```

I google that and found `Oracle` document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_09err.htm, which state...

> If the symbol SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS is defined, then the SQLCA   will be
>   defined to have this storage class. For example:
>
> ```
> #define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS extern
>
> will define the SQLCA as an extern.
> ```

so my questions...

1. What is the exact meaning of that line?
2. According to document can `#define` has the capability to provide storage?
3. can we use this as a trick in our `C/C++` codes?

I know my presentation of this question is not good, but I really want to learn that can we use this as a trick in our `C/C++` codes.

EDIT : 
starting og the .cpp file

```
#pragma warning(disable:4786)
#define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS extern
#include <sqlda.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
```

NOTE : I want to add `Pro*C` tag here but I could not find that. Please create one Tag for that.

Comment: Where is `SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS` being used in the code, can you give an example?

Comment: @MatsPetersson... I updated that.. Please check...

Comment: I asked for where it is being USED, not where it is defined (however, the answers given are probably correct - but without seeing the exact code where it is used, it could mean almost anything). It does not, however "provide storage".

Answer (score 1):

> What is the exact meaning of that line?

The exact meaning of `#define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS extern` is that it will replace `SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS` with `extern` before compilation.

> According to document can #define has the capability to provide storage?

The document doesn't talk about storage, but rather `storage class`. `extern` in C++ is a [storage class specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ash6ess9.aspx)

> can we use this as a trick in our C/C++ codes?

What trick, exactly ? :)

Answer (score 1):

> I catch one line which is not at all related to C++.
>
> `#define SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS extern`

Err. That is standard C++. Please read any book on the language.

1. It is a preprocessor command
2. It is used to provide a storage class as per document. You could make it `extern`, `static`, or `const` (or any valid combination).
3. Do not use tricks if you want your code to be maintainable. Especially not ones you clearly don't understand.

Comment: @TomTanner... Thanks...I did not use any trick until I know that. And when I do not know anything, I came up here for expert advice like you and all geeks.

Answer (score 0):

This `SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS` is a macro, which will be replaced with `extern` during the preprocessing-phase of the compilation. All it does, is to give the items you prepend with `SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS` so called "external linkage".
This means that you declare a symbol, but the definition might be in a different source-file. So eventually the linker has to find the definition of that symbol in either a header or source-file.
Simple example:

```
SQLCA_STORAGE_CLASS int item;
```

will be

```
extern int item;
```

after preprocessing and this is a definition, so the name `item` is visible during compilation. Eventually the linker will put the right item there.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx):

> The extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that it has external linkage (its name is visible from files other than the one in which it's defined). When modifying a variable, extern specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends). The variable or function may be defined in another source file, or later in the same file. Declarations of variables and functions at file scope are external by default.

Answer (score 0):

It just means here that in the included "oraca.h" header, the global `sqlca` will be seen as external.
The consequence is that you must declare it static elsewhere.